What's the point of "Opposition" parties in one party states?
Many one party states had opposition parties in their respective parliament.
Be it the DDR with their Block-Parties or current North Korea with their three minor opposition parties.
What is their purpose if noone could vote for them?
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_People's_Assembly

related https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/68743/21531


To show a facade of democracy or to create the illusion of inclusiveness and representation.
To provide a consultative role and to be critical, in order for the ruling party to see its own flaws.

https://www.scmp.com/news/china/politics/article/3136835/communist-party-not-chinas-only-political-party-there-are-eight

More like opposition party could be a way to keep track of the opposing elements in the society.

Opposition parties are usually controlled by and loyal to the primary party. #3 would be to provide the public somewhat of a curated vent for political dissatisfaction for minor issues. #4 is that its a filter trap. The opposition party usually picks up most of the would-be real opposition. So it saps support from opposition movements not controlled by the main party. In addition, opposition parties usually draw the line of what's considered acceptable opposition to the party in power.

@DavidS Sounds more like an answer than a comment, why not just write it as such?
